# how to convert an string representation of an array into an actual array type in pyspark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, casting

I have a column with data coming in as an string representation of an array

[image]

I tried to type cast it to an array type but the data is getting modified.

[image]

I tried to use regex as well to remove the extra brackets but its not working.

attaching the code below
This code is to convert the string representation of array to actual array

```
df = df.withColumn("columns", split(df["columns"], ", "))
```

This is the regex code i tried

```
df = df.withColumn(
'columns',
expr("transform(split(columns, ','), x -> trim('\"[]', x))")
```

)

would really appreciate any help

Comment: can you try the below and let me know if it helped you?

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
data = [("1", "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"), ("2", "[\"d\", \"e\", \"f\"]")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "columns"])
array_schema = ArrayType(StringType())
df = df.withColumn("columns", from_json(col("columns"), array_schema))
df.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following approach:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
data = [("1", "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"), ("2", "[\"d\", \"e\", \"f\"]")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "columns"])
array_schema = ArrayType(StringType())
df = df.withColumn("columns", from_json(col("columns"), array_schema))
df.show()
```

In the above code, I defined the schema for the array using `ArrayType(StringType())`. Next, I specified that the array contains strings.

Using the `withColumn` method, combined with `from_json`, I transformed the "columns" column into an array of strings based on the specified schema.

**Results:**

```
+---+---------+
| id|  columns|
+---+---------+
|  1|[a, b, c]|
|  2|[d, e, f]|
+---+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is one possible way to do it.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data = [
              (1, '["First", "Second", "Third"]'),
              (2, '["First"]'),
              (3, '["Second", "Third"]'),
              (4, '["First", "Fourth"]')
            ]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'val'])

df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)
print("Collect columns into list")

my_schema = ArrayType(StringType())


intermediate_df = df1.withColumn("array_string", F.from_json("val", schema=my_schema))

print("intermediate_df dataframe")
intermediate_df.show(n=20, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+---+----------------------------+
|id |val                         |
+---+----------------------------+
|1  |["First", "Second", "Third"]|
|2  |["First"]                   |
|3  |["Second", "Third"]         |
|4  |["First", "Fourth"]         |
+---+----------------------------+

intermediate_df dataframe
+---+----------------------------+----------------------+
|id |val                         |array_string          |
+---+----------------------------+----------------------+
|1  |["First", "Second", "Third"]|[First, Second, Third]|
|2  |["First"]                   |[First]               |
|3  |["Second", "Third"]         |[Second, Third]       |
|4  |["First", "Fourth"]         |[First, Fourth]       |
+---+----------------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, You can use `from_json` with `array<string>` schema

```
df.selectExpr("*", "from_json(columns, 'array<string>') AS columns")
```